# Importing data from S3 to BigQuery via Bigquery Omni (location restrictions)

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I am trying to import some data from S3 bucket to bigQuery. And, I ended up seeing the bigQuery omni option.

However, when I try to connect to the S3 bucket, I see that I am given a set of regions to choose from. In my case, `aws-us-east-1` and `aws-ap-northeast-2` as in the attached screenshot.
[image]

My data on S3 bucket is on the region `eu-west-2`.

Wondering why BQ allows us to look for specific regions on S3.
What should I be doing so that I can query data from an S3 bucket in the region where the data is uploaded to?

Answer (score 0):

The S3 service is unusual in that the names of buckets are globally unique and do not contain region information in the ARN of the bucket. However, buckets are located in regions but they can be accessed from any region.

My best guess here is that the connection location will be the S3 API endpoint that BigQuery will connect to when it attempts to get the data. If you don't see `eu-west-2` as an option then try using `us-east-1`. From that endpoint it is always possible to find out the location information of the bucket and then make the appropriate S3 client.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mark. Looks like the problem lies elsewhere. I did try selecting both the options I have. It might be something to do with the [connection](https://ibb.co/YWXNZys). Switching to the command mode to see whether I can get some relevant error messages.